# $elemMatch and $in. query for array of documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

having a collection(productList) and document like below:

```
    {   "_id":"1",
        "product_name" : "Haier 240l",
        "version" : "1.0",
        "filterInfo" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "brand",
                "value" : "Haier"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "energy_rating",
                "value" : "4 Star"
            }
         ]
    }
    {   "_id":"2",
        "product_name" : "Haier 310l",
        "version" : "1.0",
        "filterInfo" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "brand",
                "value" : "Haier"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "energy_rating",
                "value" : "3 Star"
            }
         ]
    }

    {   "_id":"3",
        "product_name" : "Samsung 275l",
        "version" : "1.0",
        "filterInfo" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "brand",
                "value" : "Samsung"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "energy_rating",
                "value" : "3 Star"
            }
         ]
    }
 {   "_id":"4",
        "product_name" : "Lg 254l",
        "version" : "1.0",
        "filterInfo" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "brand",
                "value" : "Lg"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "energy_rating",
                "value" : "3 Star"
            }
         ]
    }
```

I want to fetch all document with (i), brand:Haier **and** energy_rating:3
And (ii) brand:Haier **or** brand:Samsung **and** energy_rating:3
For (i) I tried, using elemMatch below queries:

```
db.productList.find({filterInfo: { $elemMatch: {'name':{$in:['brand','enery_rating']},'value':{$in:['Samsung','3 Star']}}}})

db.getCollection('productList').find({'filterInfo': {$elemMatch: { 'value':'Samsung', 'value' :'3 Star'} }  })

db.getCollection('productList').find({'filterInfo': {$elemMatch: {   $and:[ {'name':'brand', 'value' :'Samsung'}, {'name':'energy_rating', 'value':'3 Star' } ]} }    }) 

db.getCollection('productList').find({'filterInfo': {$elemMatch: {  'name':'brand', 'value' :'Samsung', 'name':'energy_rating', 'value':'3 Star'} }    })
```

But none of these is working correctly. I am doing some bascis wrong here (Novice here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Query

```
db.productList.find({
  "$and":[
    {"filterInfo":{"$elemMatch":{"name":"brand","value":"Haier"}}},
    {"filterInfo":{"$elemMatch":{"name":"energy_rating","value":"3 Star"}}}
  ]
})
```

You can simplify the first query using [`$all with $elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#use-all-with-elemmatch) to perform queries on arrays.

```
db.productList.find({
  "filterInfo":{
    "$all":[
      {"$elemMatch":{"name":"brand","value":"Haier"}},
      {"$elemMatch":{"name":"energy_rating","value":"3 Star"}}
    ]
  }
})
```

Second Query

```
db.productList.find({
  "$and":[
    {"$or":[
      {"filterInfo":{"$elemMatch":{"name":"brand","value":"Samsung"}}},
      {"filterInfo":{"$elemMatch":{"name":"brand","value":"Haier"}}}
    ]},
    {"filterInfo":{"$elemMatch":{"name":"energy_rating","value":"3 Star"}}}
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for `$elemMatch` in this, I would say.

First Query

```
db.productList.find({
   $and:[
         {'filterInfo.value':'Haier'},
         {'filterInfo.value':'3 Star'}
        ]
});
```

Second Query

```
db.productList.find({
   $and:[
         {'filterInfo.value':{
            $in:['Haier','Samsung']}
         },
         {'filterInfo.value':'3 Star'}
        ]
});
```

Concentrate more on data structuring in MongoDB for optimized performance.
I don't know your application logic, But is it necessary to keep all those data in an array. I don't see the need of that when you can keep data simple like **JSON 1** or if you are specific about `filterInfo` key can be designed like **JSON 2**.

**JSON 1**

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "product_name" : "Haier 240l",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "brand":"Haier",
    "energy_rating":"4 Star"
}
```

**JSON 2**

```
 {
        "_id" : "1",
        "product_name" : "Haier 240l",
        "version" : "1.0",
        "filterInfo": {
            "brand":"Haier",
            "energy_rating":"4 Star"
            }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the help and suggestion. when to use the $elemMatch, it seems we can use  . operator to access inner one. ?